# android button animation. How to get animation first, on click before activity

Tags: java, android, animation

I made a button for Android that rotates on click, but when I set a button and new activity, when I click it's just set me to new activity.

I need just this: when I click on that button, first to do animation e.g. rotate, then to execute a new activity.  Here is my code:

```
ImageButton pandaButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pandaButton2);

   pandaButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v){
           v.startAnimation(pandarotate);
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.threepandas.MENU"));
}
});
```

Comment: Activity is starting or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `animation listener`, when finish `animation` start your `activity`.
Please refer [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener(android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener))

Example code (must update based on your purpose):

```
ImageButton pandaButton2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pandaButton2);

   pandaButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View v){
           v.startAnimation(pandarotate);
}
});
pandarotate.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                startActivity(new Intent("com.example.threepandas.MENU"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

insert a delay for the length of the animation after the animation starts and before the activity starts

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Comment: Does `Thread.sleep` block the UIThread and freeze the UI, making the app appear frozen to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I use for this problem (got it from the Google I/O App Source Code on Github)

```
private static final int DELAY = 250;
private Handler mHandler;

@Override
        public void onClick(final View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button:
                    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    }, DELAY);
                    break;
            }
        }
```