# Android Button animation starting after click handler finished

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

I could see that the animation when tapping on a button starts after the stuff in the onClick method finished and was **wondering if this is an Android bug or normal behaviour?**. I could find a few posts ([this one e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41539929/android-button-animation-how-to-get-animation-first-on-click-before-activity)) about people searching how to start something after the animation ended, so I am not alone I suppose, but **I don't think this is logic at all**?

Answer (score 0):

```
   YouButton. setOnTouchListener(
    new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View myView, 
    MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            //after animation 
        }
        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
          //your animation 
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```